# C++ no matching function for list::erase

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, iterator, erase

I am currently trying to cycle through a linked list of type *char*. When an argument is met (if it holds the letter 'w') I try to delete the list item using list::erase. I was just hoping to receive some advice towards using this function, I have only seen examples with type *int* linked lists, and I cannot tell if it won't work because it is *char* or what reason. When I try to compile the following code:

```
void filterFile(list <char> &myList)
{
    list<char>::const_iterator itr;

    for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
    { 
        if (*itr == 'w' || *itr == 'W'){
            itr = myList.erase (itr);
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the compiling error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::list::erase(std::__cxx11::list::const_iterator&)’
>        itr = myList.erase (itr);

All of what I've done so far has been based off what I have found here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/.

I also read about a node method to delete items in a list. I am just hoping to get this method working as it seems better and I am curious to learn what I've done wrong.

Comment: The iterator should not be const

Comment: @Photon Incorrect. [See the signature for erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)

Comment: I suggest trying it with a regular iterator instead of a const_iterator. In my opinion the const_iterator should work, but it's worth a try to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Does your compiler support c++11?

Comment: Separately, when you do `erase` you still hit `itr++`, which means if you erased the last element you then iterate past it, and in other cases you miss checking for consecutive `W`s.  (cpprference.com is a much more reliable reference than cplusplus.com)

Comment: @songyuanyao: C++11 is right there in his error message so his compiler (which he should tell us) must have it at some level. However, it is possible that he didn't provide the C++11 setting to the linker, and it isn't linking C++11 libraries.

Comment: You should not do `itr++` after the erase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using C++11? std::list::erase only supports `const_iterator`s since c++11:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase

Comment: Thank you Tom. I did change my `const_interator` into `iterator` and is will compile and run now. Thank you for the help :) Also while im here, would anyone know how to change the value in the listed item. E.g. something like `*itr = 'p'` (in the same code as above, replacing the erase line).

Comment: @mark, That should work like you typed it here `*itr = 'p'`, on the condition that you're using a regular `iterator` and not a `const_iterator`

Comment: Thanks I just asked the question as I was trying to work that out before, but had not tried it since i changed it from a `const_iterator`. Thank you heaps for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2013-05/msg00185.html) or more specifically libstdc++ that wasn't fixed until 4.9.0

The missing overload mandated by C++11:

```
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
```

causes your code to fail.